# Python's memory-profiler reveals np.random taking up too much memory

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I am using Python's [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) to better understand how much memory my code is using and when setting up this simple example, I found a much higher memory usage than expected:

```
import numpy as np
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def func(n):
    x1 = np.random.random(n).astype(np.float32)
    x2 = np.random.random(n).astype(np.float32)
    x_sum = x1 + x2
    return x_sum


@profile
def main():
    """
    Main script calling func
    """
    x = func(1024**2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
Filename: mem-test-5.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
     4     52.7 MiB     52.7 MiB           1   @profile
     5                                         def func(n):
     6     56.8 MiB      4.1 MiB           1       x1 = np.random.random(n).astype(np.float32)
     7     68.7 MiB     11.9 MiB           1       x2 = np.random.random(n).astype(np.float32)
     8     68.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       x_sum = x1 + x2
     9     68.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return x_sum


Filename: mem-test-5.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    12     52.7 MiB     52.7 MiB           1   @profile
    13                                         def main():
    14                                             """
    15                                             Main script calling func
    16                                             """
    17     64.8 MiB     12.1 MiB           1       x = func(1024**2)
```

`x1` has the size expected (1024 x 1024 x 4 = 4194304 bytes = 4 MiB) but why does creating `x2` right after take up 12 MiB when it should also be only 4 MiB? Interestingly, this problem does not occur if using np.ones instead of np.random or if not casting `x1` and `x2` to float32 (that is, leaving them at default float64):

```
Filename: mem-test-5.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
     4     52.5 MiB     52.5 MiB           1   @profile
     5                                         def func(n):
     6     60.4 MiB      7.9 MiB           1       x1 = np.random.random(n)
     7     68.6 MiB      8.1 MiB           1       x2 = np.random.random(n)
     8     76.6 MiB      8.0 MiB           1       x_sum = x1 + x2
     9     76.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return x_sum


Filename: mem-test-5.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    12     52.5 MiB     52.5 MiB           1   @profile
    13                                         def main():
    14                                             """
    15                                             Main script calling func
    16                                             """
    17     60.6 MiB      8.1 MiB           1       x = func(1024**2)
```

I don't know if this is an issue with `np.random`, `np.float32`, the memory profiler or something else, but it's weird! Any insight much appreciated. Also, can anyone can reproduce this behavior?

Comment: 8388608 bytes is exactly 8 MiB, not 4. You will then notice that in both cases two arrays combined took approximately 16 MiB or memory, which is what they should. Not quite sure why the discrepancy between examples though.

Comment: `np.random.random(n)` create a temporary array with data type `np.float64`, so it has 8 MiB of data. Then the conversion to `np.float32` with the `.astype()` method creates another array with 4 MiB of data. The temporary array created by `np.random.random(n)` will (eventually) be freed.  Does the profiler "see" the coming and going of temporary arrays?

Comment: You're right @pavel, that was a typo: Because I cast to float32, I should be multiplying by 4, not 8, resulting in 4 MiB, not 8 MiB. I edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks WarrenWeckesser, perhaps the profiler "sees" those temporary arrays, but only in an inconsistent manner, or it only reports it sporadically? The MiBs add up if the profiler sees the temporary arrays for x2, but not for x1.